# Proper way to arrange bootstrap layout

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap

I have probably a simple question for someone with bootstrap experience. On this page: http://limitedwave.com/watsonmetals/site/, in the first section just under the nav bar I have 4 'zones'. One house a logo, directly under it some text in a box, to the right of both a large navigation grid, and under that an 'extra row' below the grid only.

I'm not laying this out properly on the bootstrap grid and I'd like to. I have the content in divs that are more or less stacked and floated with css and heavy margin manipulation to make it look as it does. Am i wrong in assuming bootstrap can layout these divs more like a table via its grid? Perhaps this might also help with the fact that as soon as I resize my browser to the next smaller size from full width mac pro size, the logo and text shift right.

```
   <section id="intro" data-speed="2" data-type="background">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid"> 

    <div id="welcome-screen" class="span16 text-left">
    <div id="lrail">      
    <div id="logocontainer">       
    <img id="logo" src="img/logo-watson.png" alt="Watson Metals, LLC." width="130" />
    </div>

    <div id="welcome-box" class="span3 text-right">
    Watson Metals manufactures quality metal building panels, for roof, siding, accessories for all building applications. We offer a pole barn package, steel siding or metal roofing for your personal specifications and needs.<br><br>
    With an array of metal panel profiles such as Tuff-Rib, R-Panel, and our standing seam profile, we can provide material for almost any application. Our standing seam profile is available in either 12” or 16” widths and can be conveniently produced on your jobsite using our portable roll-former.
    </div>
    </div>      
          <div class="span12 text-center"> 
            <div id="main-interface-container">
              <ul id="interface-list">
                <li><a class="link1" href="link1.php">Roofing Panels</a></li>
                <li><a class="link2" href="link2.php">Post Frame Buildings</a></li>
                <li><a class="link3" href="link3.php">Other Products</a></li>
                <li><a class="link4" href="link4.php">Custom Trim</a></li>
                <li><a class="link5" href="link5.php">Warranties and Information</a></li>
                <li><a class="link6" href="link6.php">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
                <li><a class="link7" href="link7.php">Energy Star</a></li>
                <li><a class="link8" href="link8.php">About Our Company</a></li>
                <li><a class="link9" href="link9.php">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li><img id="home-locations" src="img/watson-locations.png" alt="Locations" /></li>
              </ul>
            </div>


    </div>

            <div class="span8 text-center"><span class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2013 Watson Metals LLC., All Rights Reserved.</span></div>
          </div>
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Bootstrap's documentation is pretty solid.
The standard `container->row->span#` should work just fine for that grid. It should also take care of the responsiveUi issues you were having with the smaller screen.